# Windsor Castle 5 LifestylePerWebRequest missing

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

In Windsor Castle 5 the `LifestylePerWebRequest` is not more supported and I cannot find any documentation ([here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/releases) are the release notes) for this breaking change. Also in older documentation it was not mentioned, even so it existed and worked (see [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md)).

Is there a workaround or a suggested upgrade path?

Comment: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/359 https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/466 Found by Googling `windsor castle LifestylePerWebRequest source code`

Comment: @mjwills damn, i didn't find it! i googled it with your search term now again and went through all 34 results but it seems google is missing it (in my domain?).

Answer (score 15):

it has been moved to a new facility, install via NuGet

```
PM> Install-Package Castle.Facilities.AspNet.SystemWeb -Version 5.0.0
```